# how to exchange variables between extern iframe and site

Tags: html, iframe, facebook, cross-domain, javascript

for developement reasons (working with facebook-connect) i put the connect iframe in an iframe. on that way i am able to work on the connect-thing independent of my ip and don't have to develop on the live-server.

the iframe holding the connect-button iframe is on my server, accessing the same db-server as the developer version (developer version is running on localhsot).

as far as good ... BUT

how can i let the parent site know, that the user has connected, so that i get his profile-picture displayd as reaction to this?
how can i react in generally on an action/event/JS in an iframe? is there a way?
can the iframe post data to the parent site? like a time-stamp and fb_userid?

if the iframe stuff doesn't work ...
i thougt of saving the ip to the fb_userid (to db) and check matches  ... but i don't like this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to @Sarfraz Ahmed, your post was the inspiration for my solution:

With the src of the iframe, I send the current session id as GET parameter.

```
<iframe src="http://www.online_host.com/scriptxy.php?id_session=<?=session_id()?>"></iframe>
```

Then the script in the iframe makes a callback after some action, like

```
<script>
location.href="http://localhost/localscript.php?id_session=<?=$_REQUEST['id_session']?>&parameters_here=something";
</script>
```

It should be noticed, that the GET parameters name has not to be "sessionid", or "sessid", because this is not allowed with the most apache installations.

In PHP localscript.php, you do something like:

```
session_id($_REQUEST['id_session']);
session_regenerate_id();

$_SESSION['param1'] = $_REQUEST['param1'];
...
```

Now you can access the sessiondata in your current locally running PHP. Together with a triggered AJAX request interval this works good enough for development.

The thing is, i'm using CodeIgniter (with PostgreSQL and the session-plugin ecko) and getting a memory problem in the PostgreSQL driver script, which i didn't figure out until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to frames using query string format through `src` attribute of the iframe, eg:

```
<iframe src="mysite.com?var=test"............>
```